# AWS CloudFront "the distribution supports only cachable request" despite settings

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-lambda-edge

Enabled all methods:
[image]

Try to use cloud front distribution with these in aws cli:

```
    {
  "TargetOriginId": "S3-AAAAA",
  "TrustedSigners": {
    "Enabled": false,
    "Quantity": 0
  },
  "ViewerProtocolPolicy": "allow-all",
  "AllowedMethods": {
    "Quantity": 7,
    "Items": [
      "HEAD",
      "DELETE",
      "POST",
      "GET",
      "OPTIONS",
      "PUT",
      "PATCH"
    ],
    "CachedMethods": {
      "Quantity": 2,
      "Items": [
        "HEAD",
        "GET"
      ]
    }
  },
  "SmoothStreaming": false,
  "Compress": false,
  "LambdaFunctionAssociations": {
    "Quantity": 1,
    "Items": [
      {
        "LambdaFunctionARN": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:AAAA",
        "EventType": "origin-request",
        "IncludeBody": true
      }
    ]
  },
  "FieldLevelEncryptionId": "",
  "ForwardedValues": {
    "QueryString": false,
    "Cookies": {
      "Forward": "all"
    },
    "Headers": {
      "Quantity": 0
    },
    "QueryStringCacheKeys": {
      "Quantity": 0
    }
  },
  "MinTTL": 0,
  "DefaultTTL": 86400,
  "MaxTTL": 31536000
}
```

Get requests returns fine, however, I can't setup POST requests
Example of response to POST request:

[image]

I don't need to upload to S3 based on POST, I need to be able to send POST requests to static website.

**UPD:**

doesn't work with custom origin also:

**UPD:**

resolved by destroying and creating a new CloudFront with the same settings

Answer (score 1):

If you are using OAI to connect CloudFront with S3, then POST is not supported. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html#private-content-origin-access-identity-signature-version-4):

> POST requests are **not supported**.

Comment: Thank you! what is the best way to send requests to websites hosted in s3 via CloudFront?

Comment: @Irina I'm not sure. Maybe can proxy them through API gateway or lambda?

Answer (score 0):

find a way to resolve by destroying and creating a new CDN